# I can "Map network drive" to a Linux shared disk, but then "Windows cannot access \\" when browsing

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, samba, ntfs

I am trying browse into a computer on a network using the Windows 7 network viewer. The computer I want to browse is running Ubuntu 16, with a primary boot disk and a secondary non-boot disk. I have shared the second disk, and I can use the Windows "Map network drive" function with the IP of the Linux computer to see the drive. The problem is that the IP changes sometimes, and I want to just be able to browse the network and see it. However, Windows tells me that "Windows cannot access \servername," even though the computer itself shows up, and the disk is also open and viewable through "Map network drive."

I have tried the solutions posted in a bunch of similar questions here, but none of them worked for me.

The disk is mounted and shared. What do I need to do to be able to browse into the machine?

Comment: Check the logs on the file server.

Comment: As you provided no details of your network and/or your servers configuration, this question is almost impossible to answer.